# как автоматизировать простановку комментариев в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

в нескольких десятках классов по десятку методов которые нужны мне для отладки программы
например

```
...
Log.i(TAG, "Поток героя: команда лежать");

...
Log.i(TAG, "Поток врага id=" + id +  ": атака");

...
Log.i(TAG, "Поток героя: выстрел в враг " + id);
```

В релизе эти команды не нужны.

Как закомментарить и откомментарить их все одной командой?

пробовал ctrl+r заменой на "///Log.i(TAG" , но приходится бегать по всем классам

Может есть готовые решения на эту тему?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+R  - replce по всему проекту

Comment: спасибо хороший вариант.